# Correct way to write according to BEM methodology for following markup?

Tags: bem, smacss

Which is the correct way to write per BEM methodology for the following markup:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="logo__img" src="images/logo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {}
logo{}
logo__img{}
```

**Or:**

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 header">
    <div class="header__logo">
        <img class="logo__img" src="images/logo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {}
header__logo{}
logo__img{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two blocks: `header` and `logo`. `Logo` has an element - `image`. Basic structure is:

```
header {}
logo {}
logo__image {}
```

At first you should decide is wrapping div is really needed? Maybe you can just write:

```
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
```

Anyway.
If `logo` in `header` has some custom styles, for example margins or different sizes, you should add modificator `logo_modificator` to customise logo in `header`.

```
logo {}
logo_modificator {}
logo__image {}
logo_modificator logo__image {}
```

What's more I recommend you to separate `col` and `header`.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="logo__img" src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```